# Most bare-bones way to use a CPU? (How to learn)

Tags: microcontroller, cpu, assembly, instruction-set

I know a bit of programming but am brand new to lower-level stuff so please forgive the naivety of this question. What would be the most direct way of executing a series of commands on a CPU to do a basic addition of `1+2=3`? For example, at a relatively high-level, I could buy a micro-controller such as an an Arduino and write C code and compile it/execute it on the device, for example:

```
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    return a + b;
}
```

Would it be possible to purchase something like an [Intel i7](https://www.pcliquidations.com/p87795-intel-core-i7-930?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cse&utm_term=87795&r160164167166161), and, execute the assembly (compiled binary) on the chip without a whole bunch of peripherals? I guess my question is, given a CPU, what is the bare minimum that would be needed in order to execute instructions on it and return/receive some sort of output? I know in "build-your-own-computers" there's the CPU, Motherboard, RAM, monitor. power-supply, etc. but what would be the most bare-bones way to do this?

The point of this is I'm learning assembly/instructions and I'd like to go as low-level as I can go to understand how the components work, without going into the actual electronics fabrication (other than settings things up/connecting them).

Comment: The more complex the chip is, the less feasible it becomes to code it in bare metal if your goal is to actually do something high level. Remember, even if you type in assembly to perform a simple addition, you need to also write in assembly to set everything (oscillator, IO, memory, everything) up to actually get that result out of the processor so you can check it, and this can be a daunting task. And let's not forget an I7 requires a motherboard and its associated mandatory components to run.

Comment: Where would you store the code? How would you load it into memory? How would you point the i7 at the memory? Full-on processors are complicated...

Comment: I think you would actually learn a lot more, a lot more easily designing a processor for yourself in an FPGA and then writing assembly for that. What you propose above is either learning to write drivers or firmware for the I7 so low-level and highly optimized that you use assembly instead of a higher level language, or are asking if you can learn how to clear a beach by using tweezers instead of a shovel.

Comment: This question has serious problems of breadth as you fail to distinguish between hardware and software requirements, and you span both tiny flash-based MCU's and high end PC processors which need a whole board worth of support.   Realistically, get an Arduino and after making sure it works learn to write bare metal code (keep using the bootlader, that is not cheating) or get an STM32 Discovery/Nucleo board.

Comment: Doesn't get more bare bones than a PDP-11 front panel. You can do the same with a Z80, 16 Address switches, 8 Data switches and a pushbutton for "Enter". But not with an i7, sorry. https://obsolescence.wixsite.com/obsolescence/pidp-11

Comment: So, first you take a walk down to the beach and scoop up a handful of sand...

Comment: David542, I see you aren't adding to the discussion here. You should. Also, there is a really gentle introduction to how computers work at the bare metal level in a book by Clive Maxfield: [Bebop Bytes Back: An Unconventional Guide to Computers](https://www.amazon.com/Bebop-Bytes-Back-Unconventional-Computers/dp/0965193403). You won't completely design a computer from that. But you will go a very long way in grasping the basics involved. It's a good overview at just enough of a detailed level that neophytes can understand it reasonably well.

Comment: David541, Also, I like Brian Drummond's comment about a front panel. This is one of the more basic and human-connected and tactile ways of connecting you and a computer with the basics of putting something into it and getting it to run. You can single-step one instruction at a time, examine registers manually, and see the details pretty well. It's totally connected to you, too, in a physical way: not unlike how personally playing a piano connects you more deeply to music. Some say they appreciate music without knowing how to play it. I totally disagree -- playing deepens music in your soul.

Comment: @jonk -- you know your audience, I play the piano! ;) -- The PDP-11 looks like an interesting way to start...but then there looks like an ungodly level or abstraction/complexity in going to the more modern chips, which from the comments, it seems like it's not too possible to work with those directly. I've read the book `code` and the one you linked looks pretty interesting. After writing stuff for the pdp-11, what would the next level of learning/complexity be?

Comment: @DKNguyen is there an FPGA that you could recommend to buy (maybe like a starter-kit) if one exists? I would be comfortable doing the instructions, but any setup/connection/electronics stuff I'd have no idea where to even start from.

Comment: @jonk also, do you think something like this would be helpful? https://www.unicorn-engine.org/

Comment: @David542 I cannot explain to others what it is like to play music, both solo for hours at a stretch at home but also when you are creating something wonderful with others, as well. I also play drums, which taught me so much more than piano did. But I cannot even listen to music anymore. It almost hurts me. I need to play and I start looking for something so that I can get rid of the irritation of having to just sit and listen. Your body, your physicality itself, is there in the present. And those who just listen will never get it and it cannot be explained.

Comment: @David542 I don't like simulators for learning computers. You can get some things, that way. And there are some really good languages for creating a processor: [Chisel](https://www.chisel-lang.org/) is an example of such that works at a high level of expression and generates Verilog RTL. But there is nothing quite the same as having a front panel and CPU and, not to be funny but serious, an AM radio nearby so you can actually HEAR your software routines while they run. You can actually hear a software loop, for example! Or a sort routine!

Comment: @David542 Today, we have so many fancy MCUs that have grown to the point where it is very difficult to actually start at the beginning. It wasn't always like that. And I think all these advances have stolen a learning opportunity from many, today. Books written assume a level of informed education that they didn't assume before. So older books are better arranged to teach the basics with excellent explanations that provide the right foundations to build upon. Today? Not so much. It's assumed you are taking classes, not self-educating. And that's a semi-sad state of affairs today.

Comment: @David542 The modern ability to push millions if not billions of transistors onto a cheap chip has forced people to use libraries instead of direct bare-metal programming. Similarly, very sophisticated transducers exist now that require very sophisticated handling. For example, AHRS (attitude and heading reference systems) require knowledge of Adaptive-Step Gradient Descent (ASGD) modifications and Kalman filtering. Knowledge which takes years to develop. Most just blindly (and stupidly) use libraries they little understand (and they all too often get the results they deserve.)

Comment: @David542 For example, many ARM processors go through multiple steppings and bug fixes over time. (The same part number from the same manufacturer.) And in some cases this dramatically affects how you initialize the chip, just to be able to start programming it properly. Old code won't initialize correctly on new steppings. The fix is to provide a "library" that detects which stepping it is running on and performs those initializations properly for you. But you are isolated and lose sight when using libraries you must use.

Comment: @David542 You could write that code yourself. But doing that is mind-numbing and pointless as it completely distracts you by forcing you to squirrel yourself deeply into stupid nuances (stepping differences) that have little to do with learning about bare metal programming. So I'd recommend staying with 8-bit MCUs or, at worst, 16-bit (like the MSP-430 from TI.) Do NOT start with 32-bit or 64-bit, despite the temptations. They are powerfully attractive. But you lose sight. All computers have a small set of core concepts that all must use. Focus on that.

Comment: @David542 For a really "tactile" computer, see [Harry Porter's Relay Computer](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/Relay/). He provides a lot of detail and, as you can imagine, using relays to make a computer forces you to stick to the basic ideas and not go off on a tangent "getting fancy."

Comment: Unicorn is about 10 steps up the ladder.

Comment: @David542 Micronova Mercury II for is is probably the easiest to get started with if you want something that is as bare and small as possible to stick into other stuff since it has starting resources for VHDL. You could plug it into a breadboard or buy the carrier board that goes with it. There are also products from Trenz.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111198/discussion-on-question-by-david542-most-bare-bones-way-to-use-a-cpu-how-to-lea).

Comment: Look up "operating system development" or "osdev" for short. Your code still won't run on a bare CPU, but on a PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont want to mess with an intel, no.  Not a good starting path at all.  Unless perhaps you run one of the 8086/88 simulators, but even then I would not start there.

As far as learning assembly goes, pdp11 (not joking), msp430, arm thumb, arm, and a few others are good starting points, build a good foundation then each subsequent instruction set is easier.  You can start with simulations and that is not a bad path, there are pdp11 simulators (simh), msp430 there is an open core, armv2/3 open core plus countless mips and risc-v's I would do those later.  You want something supported by gnu tools so all of the above (yes there is a maintainted pdp-11 backend on binutils and gcc).  msp430 and countless arm based microcontrollers are available and those would be the best hardware place to start, that or a pi-zero (but not a full sized pi nor beagle bone black not yet).  yes there are avr's, etc but can be harder to use depending on what one you get.

Realistically there are many mcu boards in the $10 to $20 range that would be a good starting point from a cost perspective, some may require another or few $2 - $20 boards.  Going to pick one path first.

st is one of the leading companies with cortex-m (arm) based mcus that run in thumb mode which is one of the simpler arm instruction sets.  The instruction set with the most compatibility across the whole of the arm based world.

Running on linux will make your life much much easier but not required, tools can be found for Windows or OSX.

A minimal program to add two numbers for a cortex-m would be:

```
.thumb
.word 0x20001000
.word reset
.thumb_func
reset:
    mov r0,#1
    mov r1,#2
    add r2,r1,r0
    b .
```

that is it, 100% of the software

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-as flash.s -o flash.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -Ttext=0x08000000 flash.o -o flash.elf
arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy -O binary flash.elf flash.bin
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -d flash.elf > flash.list
```

The code in this answer doesnt care between arm-none-eabi- and arm-linux-gnueabi- built gnu tools.

cat flash.list

```
Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000
 8000004:   08000009

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   2001        movs    r0, #1
 800000a:   2102        movs    r1, #2
 800000c:   180a        adds    r2, r1, r0
 800000e:   e7fe        b.n 800000e <reset+0x6>
```

I am leading up to a particular board/chip/family the core actually looks for the vector table at 0x00000000 but this brand addresses the user flash at 0x08000000 then mirrors it to 0x00000000 if the chip is configured to boot from the user flash.   The first word goes into the stack pointer and the second is the reset vector address orred with one (a legacy thumb thing, roll with it).

And then you can see one register is loaded with a 1, one with a 2 then they are added together and stored in a third.

I am starting with a NUCLEO-F446RE which is currently readily available from amazon, mouser, digikey, st, etc.  Cheaper from places other than amazon but then you pay shipping.  There are $10 nucleo boards that work just fine as well.  Some of the nucleo boards dont hook the target mcu uart through the debug end of the board (another mcu), so you want to do your research first.  If you get one of these boards, then you dont for now need to buy any other hardware this is it.

The board when plugged in shows up as a virtual thumb drive, and you simply copy the .bin file over in order to load the program into the flash.

```
cp flash.bin /media/user/NODE_F446RE/
```

Now the program is loaded the processor reset and the program is running.

Using another free tool, openocd I can connect to the debugger in the mcu:

```
openocd -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/target/stm32f4x.cfg 
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 2000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
none separate
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v36 API v2 SWIM v26 VID 0x0483 PID 0x374B
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.266535
Info : stm32f4x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
```

in another window telnet into the openocd debugger, stop the core and dump the registers

```
telnet localhost 4444
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Open On-Chip Debugger
> halt
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x0800000e msp: 0x20001000
> reg
===== arm v7m registers
(0) r0 (/32): 0x00000001
(1) r1 (/32): 0x00000002
(2) r2 (/32): 0x00000003
(3) r3 (/32): 0x00000000
(4) r4 (/32): 0x00000000
```

Can see that the three registers have the values we programmed.

As well as the vector table loaded stack pointer

```
(13) sp (/32): 0x20001000
```

If I want to do this in C and make it slightly more complicated, Ill go ahead and make a more complete project.  100% of the code:

flash.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb
.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
.word 0x20001000
.word reset
.thumb_func
reset:
    bl main
    b .
```

main.c

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b );
int main ( void )
{
    return(fun(1,2));
}
```

fun.c

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    return(a+b);
}
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > ram
}
```

build

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -c main.c -o main.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -c fun.c -o fun.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T flash.ld flash.o main.o fun.o -o main.elf
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D main.elf > main.list
arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy -O binary main.elf main.bin
```

Your example program is dead code as written if optimized it would not generate an add instruction it would instead be:

```
main:
   mov r0,#3
   bx lr
```

there are other solutions but hiding the constants from the optimization

```
08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   08000009    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   f000 f802   bl  8000010 <main>
 800000c:   e7fe        b.n 800000c <reset+0x4>
    ...

08000010 <main>:
 8000010:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
 8000012:   2102        movs    r1, #2
 8000014:   2001        movs    r0, #1
 8000016:   f000 f801   bl  800001c <fun>
 800001a:   bd10        pop {r4, pc}

0800001c <fun>:
 800001c:   1840        adds    r0, r0, r1
 800001e:   4770        bx  lr
```

and the add happens.  r0 gets the 1, r1 the 2, then the add turns r0 into the 3.  So copy and run

```
> reg
===== arm v7m registers
(0) r0 (/32): 0x00000003
(1) r1 (/32): 0x00000002
(2) r2 (/32): 0x00000000
```

Last example

adding this to flash.s

```
.globl dummy
.thumb_func
dummy:
    bx lr
```

and using this main.c

```
void dummy ( unsigned int );
int main ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    for(ra=0;;ra++) dummy(ra);
}



Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000
 8000004:   08000009

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   f000 f802   bl  8000010 <main>
 800000c:   e7fe        b.n 800000c <reset+0x4>

0800000e <dummy>:
 800000e:   4770        bx  lr

08000010 <main>:
 8000010:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
 8000012:   2400        movs    r4, #0
 8000014:   0020        movs    r0, r4
 8000016:   f7ff fffa   bl  800000e <dummy>
 800001a:   3401        adds    r4, #1
 800001c:   e7fa        b.n 8000014 <main+0x4>
 800001e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
```

so both r4 and r0 will contain the count value, if we stop and start and stop we can see those count

```
> halt
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x0800000e msp: 0x20000ff8
> reg r0
r0 (/32): 0x0088B275
> resume 
> halt
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x0800000e msp: 0x20000ff8
> reg r0
r0 (/32): 0x009B0F27
> reg r4
r4 (/32): 0x009B0F27
>
```

You can then move on to blinking leds, getting the uart initialized and so on.

Here is where you understand that baremetal programming is 99% reading and research, less than 1% of your time is spent on the actual application.  You do lots of reading and write some amount of throwaway code figuring out what the manual really meant.  You also find that most of the work has to do with the peripherals and not the architecture/instruction set.  You spend more time dealing with configuring peripheral registers than dealing with configuring the processor if at all.

So there are lots of nucleo boards that support this "mbed" thing which implies that you can do the copy the bin file thing.  There are nxp based ones as well as the first mbeds were nxp based. (nxp is another company that sells cortex-m based chips).  If you invest in a nucleo board like the one mentioned above the debug end of the board can be used to debug other cortex-m based mcus even from other vendors, or for a few bucks you can get an swd based debugger or generic ftdi breakout that supports mpsse (adafruit has one for $15).  If you are willing to gamble on ebay you can get a usb uart board for a couple of bucks and an swd debugger for five bucks.  Or spend around $15 for each through amazon, adafruit or sparkfun, things that you will want in your toolbox.

Another path that is also arm based is the raspberry pi zero and a simple program on that is:

```
mov r0,#1
mov r1,#2
add r2,r1,r0
b .
```

no vector table.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
   4:   e3a01002    mov r1, #2
   8:   e0812000    add r2, r1, r0
   c:   eafffffe    b   c <.text+0xc>
```

you then copy the .bin file to an sd card and name it kernel.img.  along with bootcode.bin and start.elf that you get from the raspberry pi folks github projects.  insert the sd card into the board and power it on.

you can do jtag debugging using openocd but you will need hardware and you cant debug the above program.  The chip is gpu centric the exposed jtag is the gpu, to connect to the arm jtag debugger you need to re-configure some gpio pins to expose the jtag which means some extra arm code that configures those gpio pins, then the right ftdi breakout or other board and four jumper wires for the basic jtag signals and you can use openocd to connect to the processor and stop it and such.  Since it runs from ram, once stopped then you could load a program

```
load_image main.elf
resume 0x00000000
```

then halt load resume, repeat until you hang some peripheral or figure your program out, occasionally needing to reset to put the chip in a known state.

The other pis are much more complicated, you dont want to go there with baremetal for a long time.  The good thing about the pi's though is an excellent baremetal forum at the site with lots of folks with deep understanding of the arm core and the chips plus example code of how to do various things including the magic you will need if you want to dabble into the multi-core armv7 or armv8 cores on that platform.

There is a risc-v based board for $9 on amazon, that has a similar fake flash based loading scheme risc-v is a bit harder to get started on than arm/thumb.  so I wouldnt start here, and I dont remember what debug if anything is available on this board, so you somewhat blindly aim for blinking the led then later uart, then you can start using those to debug.

You can certainly buy arduino boards and ditch the arduino sandbox and write programs and load them, and do similar things as above.  There is an avr instruction set simulator you can use.  The harvard-ish nature of the instruction set and some other things I wouldnt start there, i migth go there later after some other instruciton set.

msp430 is a good simple starting point clearly inspired by the pdp11/lsi11  which is one of the better first instruction sets. Boards used to be a few bucks but now are probably more like $10 to $20 and can at least program the chip and blink leds for just the cost of the board with the right software.  If you want to do uart, etc you might need a usb uart board for a few to 15 bucks.

opencores has some cores you can sim with tools like verilator or icarus, but you may end up spending a lot of time getting that all working esp if you have no experience with these tools or these hardware languages.  But take the amber arm2/3 core or one of the others, figure out how to feed the core, they you can get a full experience of seeing the code execute in a core, watch the instructions get fetched, decoded, etc, etc...Once you develop code for a chip in a sim it is difficult when the silicon arrives because you now have no visibility into what is going on.  (granted the silicon runs orders of magnitude faster).

Another approach is to write your own instruction set simulator.  msp430 you can probably bang out in a long afternoon.  minimal thumb maybe a full day.  then learn to master the toolchain (just use gnu binutils and gcc) to create binaries as above, then feed your sim these programs and make/watch them run.  Writing a simulator and/or disassembler you will learn the instruction set nuances better than some professionals that have been using that instruction set for years since so few really dig into the nuances.  Using a debugged toolchain ideally means the code is good and things that are not always well documented like pc-relative addressing or branching is generated in the machine code and you can figure out how to decode that.

End of the day, dont limit yourself to one platform, the approach above has suggestions at approaches that will hopefully maximize your initial success, limit your frustration and desire to give up and never try again.  With some marks in the win column that drives motivation to keep on and grind through the failures to get at more wins.  x86 is a bit of a beast, you can certainly work your way up to it, but why?  You are not going to boot one from scratch, you can certainly start from where something like windows or linux boots from media and go from there.  An x86 box has more non-x86 processors than x86 processors, there are more arm processors in that box than x86s, and/or a smattering of others, 8051s, z80s, etc.  x86 is rapidly becoming limited to servers and for now ARM's for everything else (phones and tablets and soon to be laptops).  It is interesting to see what a full blown CISC looks like and how it works, and personally I would start with an 8088/86 emulator and have a manageable and safe experience with a high chance of success.  And then read sites like stackoverflow and intel docs to see how the current instruction set evolved over time as well as the gory details of all the protection systems, etc.

I highly recommend you instead start this journey with microcontrollers and/or simulators/emulators.  Inexpensive, folks still develop at this level, if one doesnt work for you or you brick it oh well buy another or buy a different one for another 10 bucks.  Depending on the journey you want to take you can then use free tools like kicad, and buy some $1 mcu parts, a few dollar pcb, solder the chip on yourself and open up even more chips to play with that dont have cheap eval boards.

---

EDIT

rereading the quesiton, "seeing" output other than the debugger visibility above, for that nucleo board

flash.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
.word 0x20001000
.word reset

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang
.thumb_func
hang:   b .

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
```

notmain.c

```
void dummy ( unsigned int );

#define RCCBASE         0x40023800
#define RCC_AHB1ENR (*((volatile unsigned int *) (RCCBASE+0x30) ))

#define GPIOABASE       0x40020000
#define GPIOA_MODER (*((volatile unsigned int *) (GPIOABASE+0x00) ))
#define GPIOA_BSRR  (*((volatile unsigned int *) (GPIOABASE+0x18) ))

//PA5

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int rx;

    ra=RCC_AHB1ENR;
    ra|=1<<0; //enable GPIOA
    RCC_AHB1ENR=ra;

    ra=GPIOA_MODER;
    ra&=~(3<<(5<<1)); //PA5
    ra|= (1<<(5<<1)); //PA5
    GPIOA_MODER=ra;

    for(rx=0;;rx++)
    {
        GPIOA_BSRR=((1<<5)<< 0);
        for(ra=0;ra<800000;ra++) dummy(ra);
        GPIOA_BSRR=((1<<5)<<16);
        for(ra=0;ra<800000;ra++) dummy(ra);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > ram
}
```

build

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T flash.ld flash.o notmain.o -o notmain.elf
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy -O binary notmain.elf notmain.bin
```

copy it over and the led will blink.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000
 8000004:   08000009

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   f000 f804   bl  8000014 <notmain>
 800000c:   e7ff        b.n 800000e <hang>

0800000e <hang>:
 800000e:   e7fe        b.n 800000e <hang>

08000010 <dummy>:
 8000010:   4770        bx  lr
    ...

08000014 <notmain>:
 8000014:   2101        movs    r1, #1
 8000016:   b5f0        push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
 8000018:   46c6        mov lr, r8
 800001a:   4a12        ldr r2, [pc, #72]   ; (8000064 <notmain+0x50>)
 800001c:   b500        push    {lr}
 800001e:   6813        ldr r3, [r2, #0]
 8000020:   2780        movs    r7, #128    ; 0x80
 8000022:   430b        orrs    r3, r1
 8000024:   4910        ldr r1, [pc, #64]   ; (8000068 <notmain+0x54>)
 8000026:   6013        str r3, [r2, #0]
 8000028:   680b        ldr r3, [r1, #0]
 800002a:   4a10        ldr r2, [pc, #64]   ; (800006c <notmain+0x58>)
 800002c:   4e10        ldr r6, [pc, #64]   ; (8000070 <notmain+0x5c>)
 800002e:   401a        ands    r2, r3
 8000030:   2380        movs    r3, #128    ; 0x80
 8000032:   00db        lsls    r3, r3, #3
 8000034:   4313        orrs    r3, r2
 8000036:   600b        str r3, [r1, #0]
 8000038:   2320        movs    r3, #32
 800003a:   4698        mov r8, r3
 800003c:   4d0d        ldr r5, [pc, #52]   ; (8000074 <notmain+0x60>)
 800003e:   03bf        lsls    r7, r7, #14
 8000040:   4643        mov r3, r8
 8000042:   2400        movs    r4, #0
 8000044:   6033        str r3, [r6, #0]
 8000046:   0020        movs    r0, r4
 8000048:   3401        adds    r4, #1
 800004a:   f7ff ffe1   bl  8000010 <dummy>
 800004e:   42ac        cmp r4, r5
 8000050:   d1f9        bne.n   8000046 <notmain+0x32>
 8000052:   2400        movs    r4, #0
 8000054:   6037        str r7, [r6, #0]
 8000056:   0020        movs    r0, r4
 8000058:   3401        adds    r4, #1
 800005a:   f7ff ffd9   bl  8000010 <dummy>
 800005e:   42ac        cmp r4, r5
 8000060:   d1f9        bne.n   8000056 <notmain+0x42>
 8000062:   e7ed        b.n 8000040 <notmain+0x2c>
 8000064:   40023830
 8000068:   40020000
 800006c:   fffff3ff
 8000070:   40020018
 8000074:   000c3500
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to work with a microcontroller. You can write assembly language code easily for an 8-bit microcontroller. You could use an Arduino board and AVR Studio and program it through the ICSP header with an appropriate tool. Or a PIC etc.

It's feasible to program ARM and even more complex chips in assembler but there is a lot of tedious setup and it would not be pleasant (often we use tools just to crank out the configuration code with more complex chips).

With a simple 8-bit processor there might only be 5 or 10 arcane instructions and some configuration variables set up to get it to chooch.

Comment: You hardly need to use ICSP to put bare metal code on an Arduino board; the bootloader and `avrdude` don't care where the hex file came from, and once the chip is programmed they don't have any role in *operating* it except for that brief moment before the bootloader hands over execution, which is really just a time delay away from booting directly.

Comment: @ChrisStratton True. Depends how bare to the metal you want to go.

Comment: Not really, code flashed by a bootloader is no less "bare to the metal" than code that got in there by any other means

Comment: @ChrisStratton Isn't there then a block of code written by someone else, that runs every time the processor is reset, delaying the startup?

Comment: But how does that *matter*?   If it did some actual setup it didn't revert, it would.  But it doesn't - you can load the exact same hex file with or without a bootloader, just as long as it isn't so large that it extends to the bootloader area.  I mean it's not like ISCP is "cheating" unless you do it with a toggle switch, LED... and is having a *debounced* pushbutton allowed?  Using the bootloader doesn't change the task, it just limits the investment to a single bargain clone board.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't think it's cheating, but it's not identical to starting from bare metal. The registers are probably not exactly in the power-up default states and the startup timing is quite different. We see questions regularly here from folks who have gotten stuck from differences between starting with a debugger and starting from power-up. I hope this doesn't come across as nitpicking, it's caused me some hair loss from time to time.

Comment: It really is practically identical on an ATmega; on a more complex chip like an ARM cortex people can code *themselves* into corners, mostly by ignoring the gold standard advice: when a bootloader decides to execute a target firmware, it should *reset the CPU* then read a magic value and branch before doing *anything* as unlike in the simple case of an ATmega run with UART polling, your typical ARM cortex M-whatever is too complex to code back to a pseudo-reset state.

Comment: ARM is as trivial to use as AVR for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good resource if your learning the x86 instruction set:
[Intel Microprocessors](https://www.worldcat.org/title/intel-microprocessors-80868088-8018680188-80286-80386-80486-pentium-pentium-pro-processor-pentium-ii-pentium-iii-pentium-4-and-core2-with-64-bit-extensions-architecture-programming-and-interfacing/oclc/793139408?referer=di&ht=edition)
[image]

I used this book to build my own [8088 microprocessor computer](https://www.homebrew8088.com/home), I started with the processor and ROM and then worked my way up to adding RAM and peripherals (like I/O). Very educational.

Because x86 instruction sets built upon the previous set, the instructions are mostly the same (with additions to instructions and bus width)

If you don't want to build a computer, maybe an [8051 microcontroller](https://www.electronicshub.org/8051-microcontroller-instruction-set/) would be better.

Comment: When you say build, do you mean implement? Or build-build? Like the logic of 8088 from scratch?

Comment: I mean build a computer, you wire up the IC's

Comment: @VoltageSpike thanks for this answer. Could you please explain a bit more about that book and how that could help/guide me in building up a processor or running code on it?

Comment: It explains everything about the intel instruction set and how processors work, it explains how instructions are booted, how they are loaded into the processor, how memory is accessed and how peripherals are accessed.

Comment: I have a version of that book.  Its pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to start with a simulator. Check this out:

[MARS MIPS simulator](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/)

You can use this simulator to write assembly code that you can then compile and run.

I took an advanced embedded systems class and we used this simulator to write simple programs for a MIPS processor. If I remember correctly we used this book to learn about the architecture:

[MIPS book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131420445)

The benefit of using this book and simulator is that you will get a good fundamental understanding of what is happening in a CPU.

If you really want to learn a lot, you can then use a hardware description language to design your own MIPS processor. There are complete college courses on YouTube that do just that. Then you could simulate your design and see the inner workings of the CPU. You could even go so far as to load your HDL into an FPGA and attach peripherals like buttons and LEDs and make a working computer.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible to purchase **something like an Intel i7**, and,
> execute the assembly (compiled binary) on the chip without a whole
> bunch of peripherals?

No! But you could use a simpler CPU which requires very little support circuitry.

> I know in "build-your-own-computers" there's the CPU, Motherboard, RAM, monitor.
> power-supply, etc. but what would be the most bare-bones way to do this?

At a minimum you need the CPU itself, a clock source, some 'memory' to hold the program code, and an output to see what it did. The most bare-bones possible circuit consists of the CPU, a crystal or external oscillator, jumpers or switches on the data bus to generate an opcode, and perhaps LEDs on some signal lines to show what the CPU is doing. Here's an example:-

[absolute minimum Z80 CPU test circuit](http://www.z80.info/z80test0.htm)

[image]

But this can only execute one instruction over and over, good for for testing basic CPU operation but nothing else.

To run more complex code you need a parallel RAM or ROM chip, which you can program separately and then insert into the circuit. Next step is to add an address decoder so you can have both ROM and RAM, a machine code 'monitor' program in the ROM for interactive programming, and a serial I/O chip to connect to a 'terminal' (your PC), and then you have a complete single board computer.

Comment: I love this offering. It's simple -- most especially because the Z80 was made to be simple for "regular folks" to wire up and use (night and day when compared to the NMOS 8080A with its 8238 which you pretty much had to have as doing it discretely was a nightmare.) The Altair 8800 front panel had all the needed logic to inject a single-stepped JMP so as to move the PC where you directed it. I suppose something similar could be added to the Z80 to make this more "real" in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know everything about assembly language for the Intel processors I would check out Randall Hyde's "The Art of Assembly Language Programming" book.  Its downloadable as a free PDF on his website.

https://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/

He goes through everything from basic logic optimization to the details of how to program for 16-bit and 32-bit Intel processors as well as programming in assembly in a Linux or Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

Back when "CPU" meant a box with switches and light on the front panel, Then the minimum configuration would be the CPU itself, and a memory system, and the bus that connected them, and the power supplies.*

[image]

Then, you could use those switches and lights to examine and modify memory locations and the PC register, and at least one of those switches would let you "run" or "halt" or "single step" the program.

If you don't have a front panel, then you are going to need some kind of *peripherals* attached to the system to get information in and out.

A modern [microcontroller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) is a single chip that has a CPU, RAM, programmable ROM, and various different peripherals all on the same chip. Microcontrollers need very little external support. A [crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator), a couple of capacitors, 3.3V power, and, of course, some [means to program it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-system_programming).

One way to get started with microcontrollers is to buy an eval board (e.g.,
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nxp-usa-inc/FRDM-KL25Z/FRDM-KL25Z-ND/3529594 ).

[image]

The one above has a microcontroller with some of the pins wired to useful things (a push button, an LED, a USB-to-Serial-port adapter,) and other pins connected to a header. It also (and this is the good part) has an on-board programmer, so you don't need to buy [one of these](http://www.pemicro.com/multilink/). Power comes from your computer or from a USB wall wart via. the same USB connector that you use to program it.

It also should come with a link to all of the manuals and free-downloads for all of the programming tools that you'll need.

---

* Toward the end of the front-panel era, all that stuff became small enough to actually fit in the same box with the CPU itself!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old MP3 player supported by Rockbox, you might find looking through the source code used to boot the player very interesting.  For example, on a Sandisk Clip, you can see the bootloader which is branched to immediately after the device finishes running its onboard mask ROM:

https://git.rockbox.org/cgit/rockbox.git/tree/bootloader/sansa_as3525.c

The main function sequentially calls:

```
system_init();
kernel_init();
enable_irq();
lcd_init();
backlight_init();
button_init_device();
storage_init()
usb_int()
```

From there you can see  system configures its CPU, memory and peripheral hardware clocks, and then eventually works up to being a functioning MP3 player.  Aside from a little bit of assembly that runs before the main() to set up the c runtime:

https://git.rockbox.org/cgit/rockbox.git/tree/firmware/target/arm/crt0.S

It is almost all in c.  There are similar bootloaders for ipods, and many other devices.

Answer (score 0):

How about a fun version that's ALMOST bare metal?

The actual silicon for the old 6502 chip (the cpu inside the original Apple-II,) has been completely taken apart by hobbyists, and you can play with it online right now.  Type in some opcodes.  Single-step through it, and watch the voltages changing on the aluminum traces inside the chip.  Zoom in to examine interesting spots.

http://www.visual6502.org/

Here's their presentation on the project, w/Siggraph-2010 slide show:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi7Sy7SYlSo&t=80

.

---

Wow, also someone actually built one of these chips in hardware.  On pcb using transistors!  Plus some (non-canon) extra components, colored LEDs.

https://monster6502.com

.

---

PS

The Visual-6502 project is working on many other ancient primitive CPU chips, and it appears that they have the Moto 6800 up and running too...

http://www.visual6502.org/JSSim/expert-6800.html

Answer (score -1):

In college, i programmed a Motorola 68000 firmware board in assembly.  I had to actually look up the opcodes and type them in.  It looks like similar boards are still available.  http://www.easy68k.com/paulrsm/mecb/mecb.htm